# Certain users aren't showing up in /users when filter is applied

Tags: bug, users, filter

**NB: The `filter` parameter in v1.x of the API had a different meaning to the `filter` parameter in v2.0**

---

Consider the following query:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users?filter=jon%20skeet

This yields the profile of Jon Skeet as expected. However, when attempting to retrieve the profile of another Stack Overflow user using the same method:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users?filter=george%20edison

...I don't get any results even though I am most definitely a user on Stack Overflow and my username is "George Edison".

---

**Edit:** It's happening again:

> http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/users?filter=george

...it's not finding me and I'm [definitely on the site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4626/george-edison) under the name "George Edison". Here is a screenshot of the above URL in Chrome:

[image]

---

**Edit:** here is another example:

> http://api.serverfault.com/1.1/users?filter=George
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ```
> {
>   "total": 0,
>   "page": 1,
>   "pagesize": 30,
>   "users": []
> }
> ```

Comment: why does Community keep dredging up old questions?

Comment: @Jonathan: That's intentional - the community user bumps old unanswered questions periodically to draw attention to them.

Comment: That can be great on other sites, but like this question doesn't need answering anymore really. It's looking too far back.

Comment: @Jonathan: It certainly does - I'm still experiencing this problem.

Comment: Isn't this for v1.x API though?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this bug, both queries return what I'd expect (and variations work as well).

Comment: That's odd... it's working for me now. But it honestly wasn't working at all last week.

Comment: It's happening again - I took a screenshot this time.

Comment: @George - OK, I'll take another look tomorrow.  At least we know it wasn't a one off thing if it's recurring (though I still couldn't reproduce *just* now... caching maybe).